# How to read an word document in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, ms-word, fopen

Can we read an word document(.doc) by an command fopen in matlab 6.1?

If No please provide some information about the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [OfficeDoc utility on the Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15192-officedoc-readwriteformat-ms-office-docs-xlsdocppt) to read/write/format Word documents (plus Excel & PowerPoint docs) from within Matlab.

Comment: The linked code is long obsolete and in any case does not run under versions of MATLAB > 6.0

Comment: This is pure libel. The code runs well on Matlab 7 and newer releases, despite the fact that it was posted back in 2017 (10 years and ~25 Matlab releases ago!). The utility's source code includes ~3000 lines of code and in the past 10 years since it was posted I have not seen any other utility (or builtin Matlab functionality) that comes close to its functionality. The fact that you'd like me to provide its source code is your problem, not mine or anyone else's. It's certainly not grounds to troll around the internet defaming a utility that did you no harm.

Comment: Then why your statements over at FileEx that it won't run (at least not the executable you posted there) ?   Further,  I'm fully in the CRAN repository maintainers' camp. They require not only source code for anything posted but also that the posted packages be actively maintained to remain available.  If you want to go to a commercial product you might want to read MathWorks'  T&C about code poste to FileEx.

Comment: I never said it doesn't run - I only said it's no longer supported. I point readers to my record as a top contributor on Matlab's File Exchange for the past decade, in all aspects: number of submitted files, number of submitted code lines, average user ratings, number of downloads. I was and am consistently and continuously ranked in the top 3-5 on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors for most of the past decade. 99% of what I submitted was open-sourced and there were good reasons that officedoc was not. I do not have to answer to you or anyone else about those reasons.

Comment: Moreover: when I posted officedoc in 2007, posting p-codes was perfectly ok. You may be a CRAN old-timer but apparently you're new to Matlab if you have never heard of me or my books or website or my solid reputation in the Matlab community in general. CRAN regulations have no bearing on FEX. Something forbidden on CRAN may be perfectly ok on FEX. Regardless, if you say that "something does not run" then you better be 100% certain that you've tested it carefully on various configurations to back up your claim. In general I advise humility and prior research before defaming another user's work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 6.1 but 7.10 will fopen a Word document.  That's easy.  The challenge is now to do something useful with its contents.  Over to you.

Comment: Thank u for your answer but in matlab 6.1 fopen is not working. I tried by activex control but iam not able to select the data from the document. If u know activex please help on the same. The data i need to select is from the data [REQ1] to the data [REQ2] in the document.